# Hide column from a left join select

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

Struggling a little on this, hopefully I can get some answers here. I am trying to remove a column that appears in my results from the SQL command. I don't want 'player_id' to be showing up twice (the second time it shows is coming from the below join statement). Tried manipulating the join statement but everytime I do, it fails to then fetch the data.

```
select * from org_members
left join (select player_id, LISTAGG(ship_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP 
(order by ship_name) as Ships
from member_ships 
group by player_id) ships
on org_members.player_id=ships.player_id
```

Just as an FYI, running this through APEX on oracle 11gXE.

EDIT: here is hte output
[image: select]

Comment: You can always specify the columns you do want to show. In case of joint tables as in your case. You can select columns from any table by specifying the table name (or alias) as a prefix. Like so: org_members.player_id.

Comment: don't post pictures. rather post it as plain text

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I was showing the output, not hte code itself. The same code is just above and appropriately marked. I cant copy paste a table up here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `player_id`, then the safest thing is to list the columns that you do want.

However, there is a short-hand if you want to use `*`:

```
select *
from org_members om left join
     (select player_id,
             LISTAGG(ship_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (order by ship_name) as Ships
      from member_ships 
      group by player_id
    ) ships
    using (player_id);
```

The `using` clause does exactly what you want.

In your case, though, I would still be explicit about the columns:

```
select om.*, ships.ships
from org_members om left join
     (select player_id,
             LISTAGG(ship_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (order by ship_name) as Ships
      from member_ships 
      group by player_id
    ) ships
    using (player_id);
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay @gordon This worked. Somehow my query builder in APEX was not recognizing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure unless you show your current output but instead you should say like below. Unless you select the column it shouldn't appear twice.

```
select org_members.* from org_members
```

Per your comment, in that case you should manually specify the column names instead of using `*` like

```
select org_members.player_id,.....,ships.name,....
```

Comment: Added the output (hiding the data itself)

Comment: Your code will actually only result in the original table showing - the join will not work at all. If i input your code, the last 2 columns (join section) go missing

Comment: @PaulGerardGleeson, yeah guessed it and my posted answer should do the work

Comment: @PaulGerardGleeson, see edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: I need all the columns from the 1st table. Its the column player_id that comes from the left join htat needs to be hidden